# Tensorflow modified onehot encode

Tags: tensorflow, label, relation, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to twist the loss function a little bit, such as below.

```
Ants, Cockroach, Horse, Pig
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

And of course it will be used in tensorflow code like below:

```
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self.y, logits=self.logits)
```

I was thinking since ants and cockroach are insects as horse and pig are Mammalia, I would like to add some points to it for example,

```
Ants: [1, 0.5, 0, 0]
Cockroach: [0.5, 1, 0, 0]
Horse: [0, 0, 1, 0.5]
Pig: [0, 0, 0.5, 1]
```

I thought it would add some relativity(or relationship) of other label(s) in back propagation of the loss function. However I am not sure if

```
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
```

will use the additional information I added in the one hot encode(which is not one hot anymore). I tried to follow tensorflow code but I am still not sure though.

If it is not applying as I intended then how can I apply this to be used in back propagation? Will tensorflow allow it to be used in this way?

Comment: Your new encoding does not make any sense to me. Instead, you could try adding 2 output nodes (one for Mammalia, one for insects) and use `tf.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` instead (as the classes are not mutually exclusive anymore).

Comment: Think about binary cross entropy. It will go like this `tf.reduce_mean(
        -(y * tf.log(output_sigmoid) - (1 - y) * tf.log(1 - output_sigmoid))` where y is in one hot vector form. So I thought tensorflow might use one hot as a regular vector to continue multiplication with log functions. In this case 0.5 will be used to give the other labels in relation cost much less than the one with 0. The reason why I don't make it as two outputs and trying to add 0.5 is because I want them to be distinguishable but fairly related to each other.

Comment: The loss contributed by output nodes with the 0.5 encoding will never reach 0. Its minimum value is at `-log(0.5) = 0.301` per node. This could cause your training to not converge or its performance could be worse than a network using extra output nodes.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned above, its performance is quite similar to the one with regular one hot vectors. It merges to the case where its own turn of one hot vector is 1. I am suspicious whether 0.5 is automatically dropped in tensorflow (for example, it only considers the max as the correct label and others wrong) OR 0.5 still gives some optimization convergence although it converges half of the speed where it is on 1